# How to end a python program that launches automatically when raspberry is turned on?

Tags: python, shell, raspberry-pi

I would like to know if I could implement a condition that could stop a python program that starts running when I turn on my raspberry. I want to save data as soon as the raspberry is turned on but I would to be able to stop it when I decide, like a CTRL + C on the terminal.

Thank you

I haven't really found anything on the internet. If I launch the code myself I can stop it with CTRL + C but is there an other way to stop a Python program without a terminal window?

Comment: If you could find out its PID, you could use `kill` to stop it.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to find its PID pls ?  I don't know what it is sorry.

Comment: Ok, but that's what Google is for.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends somewhat on how you started it - you may have started it:

- as a `systemd` service, or
- from the `/etc/rc.local` script, or
- from a `crontab` entry

---

If you started it as a `systemd` service, you would use `systemd` to stop it too, like this:

```
sudo systemctl stop YOURSERVICE
```

---

If you started it by one of the other two methods, you will probably want to stop it using a signal, which you would send via the `kill` program - see `man kill` for manpages. In order to do that, you would probably want to use its `pid` or *"process id"* which is a unique number the OS assigns to each process for the purpose of managing it. You can see a list of all process ids with:

```
ps -aef
```

The `pid` is in the second column. So, we can start a little process that sleeps for 60 seconds and goes into the background so we can continue using the terminal like this:

```
sleep 60 &
```

Then look up its `pid` with the following, being careful not to find ourselves looking for it, with:

```
ps -aef | grep -v grep | grep sleep
```

**Sample Output**

```
501 17016  2906   0 11:49am ttys001    0:00.00 sleep 60
```

then kill it with:

```
kill 17016
```

This is fine, and will work for you, but it's a bit of a pain looking things up, so many daemons/services write a `pidfile` somewhere in the filesystem when they start and then they can be killed much more simply. So, if you added a couple of lines at the start of your Python data acquisition program, it could record its own `pid` in a file called `/tmp/acq.pid` like this:

```
from pathlib import Path     # to easily write in a file
import os                    # to get "pid"

# Get pid and write in file
myPID = os.getpid()
Path('/tmp/acq.pid').write_text(str(myPID))

...
rest of your normal code
...
```

Then you can easily kill it any time with:

```
pkill -F /tmp/acq.pid
```

If it was started as `root`, you may need to use:

```
sudo pkill -F /tmp/acq.pid
```